# Using Google map APi in html

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I had used Google MAP with android before but now I want to use it with in my webpage.My idea is that I have a webpage in which there is a textfield .When I will enter America in it then It must show me the Satellite view of America.I had not used any Google Map with HTML before.One idea is to use Php curl with it,Can anyone tell me how i can do this?

Comment: Have you looked at the Google Maps API examples?

Comment: Yes but i havent found any for HTML

Comment: Not sure what you mean. They are all for HTML, aren't they?

Comment: No i haven't found any library for html there..I had read the Javascript API 3

Comment: Why can you not work with JavaScript? The end result is a HTML page nevertheless. If you want to work without JavaScript, you'll have to use static maps but they are much, much more limited than normal, JavaScript-driven Google Maps.

Comment: But how should i use the Javascript API to pass the argument ?like America,Canada,Austrlia etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you send a geocoding request to Google's Geocoder, for example for "USA":

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=USA&sensor=false
```

you will get an JSON result. Part of that result will be the viewport:

```
 "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 64.73664149999999,
              "lng" : -30.14648320
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : -5.70344770,
              "lng" : -161.27929880
           }
        }
```

also available as XML:

```
 http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=USA&sensor=false
```

these are the boundaries of a rectangle that covers the entire area of the USA.

Using these coordinates, you can then proceed to the "normal" Google Maps API examples and have the map show exactly that bounding box.

Use the `fitBounds` parameter in the [Map's constructor](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map). `fitBounds` is an object of the type [`LatLngBounds`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLngBounds) that you need to construct out of the viewport's coordinates.

It's not entirely trivial to do, but definitely possible. You can use PHP to make the first XML request, then output the JavaScript to generate the map.

Comment: Nice answer.  Minor issue: your text is about XML but your example URL and code is for JSON.

Comment: Oops...you've still got JSON in your example result rather than XML.

Comment: @John argh, where is my head these days. *Now* it is fixed. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have the full documentation of Google Maps + JavaScript Api [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/). It supports Reverse Geocoding([example](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/services.html#ReverseGeocoding)), which is translating addresses to coordinates(including names like America)